# Sort but have uniform distribution for a second variable if values are same

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy

I have 2 columns: Col1, Col2 in a pandas dataframe. Col1 has numbers from 1 to 100 and Col2 has 0s and 1s.

I want to sort this dataframe in such a way that the rows are sorted by Col1. In my case, I have a few million rows, and so definitely Col1 values will be repeated many times.

I can do a `data = data.sort_values('Col1')` to sort the values based on Col1. For example, this can give:

```
Col1 Col2 ... OR ... Col1 Col2 ... OR ... Col1 Col2
100  0               100  1               100  0
100  0               100  1               100  0
100  1               100  1               100  0
100  0               100  1               100  0
100  1               100  0               100  1
100  1               100  0               100  1
100  1               100  0               100  1
100  0               100  0               100  1
99   1               99   1               99   1
...                  ...                  ...
```

There can be many possible distributions for Col2 when Col1=100 based on the sorting algorithm I use (quicksort, mergesort, etc).

In the sections where my Col1 is the same value, I want the distribution of my Col2 to be uniform, Like so:

```
Col1 Col2
100  0
100  1
100  0
100  1
100  0
100  1
100  0
100  1
99   1
...
```

Is there any sort method that python/numpy/pandas/[any other library] has that can do this ? Any ideas of an algorithm which can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the good rank to altern 0 and 1, at the beginning of each group :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':randint(0,100,1000),'col2':randint(0,2,1000),}) 
df.sort_values(['col1','col2'],inplace=True)
cnt= df.groupby(['col1','col2']).col1.count()
df['rk']=np.hstack([list(range(n)) for n in cnt])
df.sort_values(['col1','rk'],inplace=True)
```

Some explanations :

First sort `df`:

```
df.sort_values(['col1','col2'],inplace=True)
```

Then count each values :

```
cnt= df.groupby(['col1','col2']).col1.count()
```

And make the rank :

```
df['rk']=np.hstack([list(range(n)) for n in cnt])
```

The solution is then :

```
df.sort_values(['col1','rk'],inplace=True)
```

with `df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':randint(0,100,1000),'col2':randint(0,2,1000),})` :

```
     col1  col2  rk
161     0     0   0
1       0     1   0
253     0     0   1
118     0     1   1
471     0     0   2
391     0     1   2
582     0     0   3
444     0     1   3
579     0     1   4
735     0     1   5
887     0     1   6
111     1     0   0
57      1     1   0
......
```

Comment: Eas trying this out and `df['rk']=sum([list(range(n)) for n in cnt])` gives an error. Could you check? I was unable to reproduce the result

Comment: I put the code in block to avoid typo error. what is the error message ?

Comment: It essentially says that you cant do `sum` on a list of lists. `sum([[1,1], [2,2]])` doesn't work either. It gives `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`. It requires a list of ints

Answer (score 0):

An idea I can think of is creating a new column that its values represent the order:

```
offset_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 2))

def get_offset(row):
    step = offset_dict[row["Col1"]][row["Col2"]]
    offset_dict[row["Col1"]][row["Col2"]] += 1
    return row["Col1"] + 1.0/step

df["offset"] = df.apply(get_offset, axis=1)
df = df.sort_values("offset")
```

For input of the form:

```
    Col1  Col2
0    100     1
1    100     1
2    100     1
3     99     1
4    100     0
5    100     0
6     99     1
7     99     0
8     99     0
9    100     0
10    99     0
11   100     1
12   100     1
13   100     0
14   100     0
```

The output will be:

```
    Col1  Col2      offset
10    99     0   99.250000
6     99     1   99.333333
8     99     0   99.333333
3     99     1   99.500000
7     99     0   99.500000
12   100     1  100.166667
14   100     0  100.166667
11   100     1  100.200000
13   100     0  100.200000
2    100     1  100.250000
9    100     0  100.250000
1    100     1  100.333333
5    100     0  100.333333
0    100     1  100.500000
4    100     0  100.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `cumcount`, then sort by the col, and the count:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#data from B. M.

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.randint(0,100,1000),'col2':np.random.randint(0,2,1000)}) 

#make a new column, with the cumulative count for each of col1:col2
df['values'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount()

#sort by the col1, and values:
df.sort_values(['col1', 'values'])

    col1    col2    values
61  0   1   0
213 0   0   0
173 0   1   1
473 0   0   1
266 0   1   2
```

This will fail if they are very unbalanced!

As a quick hack, to sort by unbalanced, we can correct by the count of each value, and divide our index by that:

```
#make a new column, with the cumulative count for each of col1:col2
df['values'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount()

#sort by the col1, and values:
df.sort_values(['col1', 'values'])
#merge in a count of each value
df = df.merge(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index())
#make a key of index/count
df['sortkey'] = df['values']/df[0]
#sort
df.sort_values(['col1', 'sortkey'])

    col1    col2    values  sortkey 0
393 0   0   0   0.000000    3
812 0   1   0   0.000000    4
813 0   1   1   0.250000    4
394 0   0   1   0.333333    3
814 0   1   2   0.500000    4
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "uniform distribution". Will you be applying some specific test that has to pass a particular threshold? If you just need it to be "uniform enough" or "unpredictable", you can just randomize within each value of Col1.

```
# setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':randint(0,100,1000),'col2':randint(0,2,1000),})

# add a column with random numbers
df['random_col'] = np.random.random(len(df))

# two-level sort 
df.sort_values(['col1','random_col'])
```

Comment: Hm, so I basically want (probabilistically, if necessary) that the 0s and 1s are evenly distributed when Col1 has same value. My final aim is that in any chunk of data I take (let's say first 10% of rows with Col1=99) the average Col2 should be same. I get that first 10% may not be same as 1%-11% because this is discrete data. But probabilistically would be enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for asking this question about "how uniform". It makes me realize that maybe the question was not well defined. And helps me re-think on how to frame this question.